# How can I check for existence of a hyper edge in Neoeloquent?

Tags: laravel, neo4j, neoeloquent

having a defined hyperMorph method in my model and some polymorphic relationships in my Neo4j DB, I've tried these two lines for checking the existence of relationship but both return true , even when there is no a relation between the three nodes:

```
$e=$parent->function($related)->edge($hyper)->exists();
```

and

```
$e=$parent->function($related)->getEdge($hyper)->exists();
```

where is the problem with these two?

Answer (score 0):

The `getEdge($hyper)` method that you're calling, constructs the relationship with the given models and returns it, with `exists` it will check if both sides of the relationship exist and whether they do exist in the database (the models not a relationship between them), hence it is always giving you that the relationship exists since you constructed it with `getEdge`.

In order to work with queries that has to do with fetching records only when a relationship exist, use `has` and `whereHas`.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations under Querying Relationship Existence.